# Objective C problem defining properties

Tags: objective-c

When I attempt to define an int as a property in Objective C i get an error (not of type object). I have tried using NSInteger and int but neither work.

code:
   int seat;

@property (nonatomic, retain) int seats;

Comment: NSInteger is a typedef for an integer (in 32-bit applications) or a long (in 64-bit applications) so in your scenario, if you're writing a 32-bit app, using int and NSInteger are the same thing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot retain an int or a NSInteger as they are primitive types - not objects. Use the following instead:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int seats;
```

Comment: Clearer would be @property (nonatomic, assign) int seats;